# Model namespacing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, mongoid

I would like to have a model user like this:

```
class User
  include User::Devise # or better, include Devise

  # more code 
end
```

I am using mongoid, that's why User does not inherit ActiveRecord::Base.

But I would like to define my devise configurations in another file `app/models/user/devise.rb`:

```
module User::Devise

  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# more devise stuff
```

How could I achieve what I am trying?

## Update

I can make this work writing in `app/models/devise_user.rb`:

```
module DeviseUser
  # code here
```

I suppose this option is good enough, but to have `app/models/user/devise.rb` is more organised.

Comment: What happens if you run this code?

Comment: it says warning: toplevel constant Devise referenced by User::Devise

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: Finally I understood what's wrong. `Devise` is the root module, and you are trying to `include Devise` that is the nested in `User`. Since you are doing `devise :registerable` - it includes Devise root module into the `User`, since it's already added with include it tries to add it again, the same module. I've changed naming to `User::DeviseOverrides` and now it works. A little bit weird, but I don't know solutions how it's possible to include already defined module that is exists in the other path. I guess somehow it's possible reopen module, but I'm stick with different naming.